# VBA -> NPOI excel reading c#

Tags: c#, vba, excel, apache-poi, npoi

Good day
I am trying to use NPOI to read 2 excel files. One file acts as a "key" of sorts where I do some sumifs, indexs and matches between the two when open. Here is a snippet of VBA code below that works perfectly. The two excel files are "wb" and "wb2" (sorry for my terrible naming conventions).

```
With wb2.Sheets(4)
lastRow3 = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With


With wb.Sheets(2)
lastRowwb2 = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

For Each cell In wb.Sheets(2).Range("A1:A" & lastRowwb2)
    cell.Offset(0, 3) = Application.SumIf(wb2.Sheets(4).Range("B" & firstrow & ":B" & lastRow3), cell.Value, wb2.Sheets(4).Range("K" & firstrow & ":K" & lastRow3))
Next cell

For Each cell In wb.Sheets(2).Range("F1:F" & 3)
    If cell.Offset(0, 1) <> 0 Then
        occupancy = occupancy & cell.Offset(0, 0) & " - " & Format(cell.Offset(0, 1), "Percent") & ", "
    Else
    End If
Next cell
```

Here below is my start to the c#

```
 // compariosn files
        ISheet sheet = hssfwb.GetSheet("GEOCODING");
        ISheet sheet1 = hssfwb.GetSheet("GEODISTRIBUTION");
        ISheet sheet2 = hssfwb.GetSheet("OCCUPANCY");
        ISheet sheet5 = hssfwb.GetSheet("CONSTRUCTION");
        ISheet sheet9 = hssfwb.GetSheet("NUMSTORIES");
        ISheet sheet10 = hssfwb.GetSheet("FLOORAREA");



        //coding sheet
        ISheet sheet3 = hssfwb1.GetSheet("Occupancy");
        ISheet sheet4 = hssfwb1.GetSheet("Fire to RMS");
        ISheet sheet6 = hssfwb1.GetSheet("Construction");
        ISheet sheet7 = hssfwb1.GetSheet("ATC Consturction");
        ISheet sheet8 = hssfwb1.GetSheet("FIRE Classes");

        for (int row = 0; row <= sheet3.LastRowNum; row++)
        {
            sheet3.CreateRow(row).CreateCell(3).SetCellFormula("");
        }

        for (int row = 0; row <= 2; row++)
        {
            if (sheet3.GetRow(row).GetCell(6).ToString() != "0")
            {
                string occupancy = sheet3.GetRow(row).GetCell(5).ToString() + " - " + sheet3.GetRow(row).GetCell(6).ToString() + ", ";
            }

        }
```

I am not sure how to run the formula on one sheet using another sheets values (different files)